# create image from character

Tags: image, fonts, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm using standard styles for my `Metro` app. Most of these styles contains an `Image` and I wanna use `Segoe UI Symbol`s as these images.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the "character" in any text content that is using the Segoe UI Symbol as the font.  If I wanted a Favorite's Star in a TextBlock, it would look like this...

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="372,375,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="&#xE113;" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
```

If I wanted to make a button that had the same "character" in it, I would do this...

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="&#xE113;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="372,181,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button_Click" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="24"  Height="79" Width="128"/>
```

If I wanted the button to take on the circle AppBar button style, I would add the Style resource like this...

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="&#xE113;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="372,181,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button_Click" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="24" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Height="79" Width="128"/>
```

Same type of approach if you are using HTML.  Just make sure you styles are correct...

```
<span class="pagetitle">&#xE113;</span>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you would do this in the code behind. I've tried as follows but in this case, not the star-icon will be displayed but the plain code as text (I am working with a RichTextBlock):

Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
Run starSign = new Run();
starSign.Text = "&#xE113;";                                starSign.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Symbol");
para.Inlines.Add(starSign);       
MyRichTextBlock.Blocks.Add(para);

Comment: Ok, I've found the answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050255/how-do-i-use-xaml-hexnumbers-for-windows-store-app-icons-segoe-ui-symbol-in-da#answer-14057060