# Windows 8: Creating AppBar Style Buttons with HTML5/CSS

Tags: html, css, windows-8, appbar

For a Windows 8 Application, I can create AppBar style buttons using 'Segoe UI Symbol' but they have drawn in a rectangle area therefore has a rectangle background. Since I want to set their background to a different color during hover, I need to get rid of this rectangle.

As pointed out in below question, the button and the style are defined like shown.

Please give a direction how this can be accomplish.

[create image from character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037888/create-image-from-character/12039643#12039643)

HTML:

```
<button id="myAppBarIcon" class="normal-size-icon">&#xE1D8;</button>
```

CSS:

```
.normal-size-icon {
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: 630px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Symbol';
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Update:

Below code does the trick but font is not properly aligned. Probably because it is not made to align properly. Image below shows the layout.

```
.normal-size-icon {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Symbol';
    color: rgb(555, 255, 255);
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image: Font does not align properly]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what the incorrect behavior is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this point you need to set `border-radius:50%;` so you your button will change shape to circle then add `min-width:0; min-height:0;` and `text-align:center;` here is the full css :

```
.normal-size-icon {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Symbol';
    color: rgb(555, 255, 255);
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

if you don't need border you can set `border:none;`. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: It does the trick, thanks but I think the symbol is not made to align neither vertically nor horizontally. It looks like in my updated question. Whatever I did, I could not make it align properly.

Comment: Well I don't know why your symbol is not align properly but I tested it in my project it work just fine the symbol is aligned to center. Did you set any other style to the id of the button?

Comment: Oh I see. A separate project does not show the problem. Thanks for the answer, marking it now.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :). You better clean and rebuild your project so that your project will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is driven by the `CSS hover selector`, and the default CSS there for a button will provide something that aligns with the light or dark theme, e.g.,

```
button:hover, input[type=button]:hover, input[type=reset]:hover,
input[type=file]::-ms-browse:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

You could override this very specifically with something like:

```
.normal-size-icon:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

but there are likely additional states and objects for which you'd want similar treatment.

Take a look at the `ui-light.css` and `![ui-dark.css][1]` that's included in your References; all the answers are in there :)

[image]